# Limiting session time

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, gpo

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 on which a policy needs to be set. This policy should logoff a user if it is disconnected or idle for more than 2 hrs.

One twist is, I have a user with name 'Invo' which should not get kicked out due to this policy.

Comment: Hello, Welcome to StackOverflow . You should keep in mind stack overflow is not a code writing service but is instead a resource to get help with developing issues you are facing. Please read more about how to ask a question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your setup, I take it that the user is part of the OU the other users that you want to apply this GPO to. Other thing you could look at is using security filtering to only apply the GPO to a certain group or people, but this also would depend on the amount of users you have.